# export android library as a .jar file

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I've just created an android library module, and now I'd like to export it as a .jar file (Like I used to do in Eclipse), so I can use it in others project just link it as an external library file.

The problem is that I've just read from the official site that "You cannot export a library module to a JAR file": https://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html

So how can I do that? Is there something similare that I can do to obtain the same result?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must export it as `.AAR` file. It is not possible to export an Android Studio library as a `.jar` file.

**[Android .AAR Format](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/aar-format)**

Check this out: https://androidbycode.wordpress.com/2015/02/23/building-an-aar-library-in-android-studio/

> **Purpose of AAR:** Library reuse has long been available in Java based
>   applications through Java Archive (.jar) files.  Android AAR files
>   build upon this concept to allow you to package not only the source
>   code but also the libraries self contained Android resources. The
>   library can have its own manifest and resources and can also
>   optionally provide assets, NDK built libraries, proguard configuration
>   and even its own custom lint filters.  This is all bundled into a zip
>   archive that can be published to a repository for your team (or the
>   world!) to get easy access from a Gradle build.

This is how to create the .AAR file by @alex18aa:

`File` -> `New module` -> `Import aar/jar`, and then add the dependencie in the module settings, and linking it.

Comment: So I can just use the .aar output as the old .jar in others android project?

Comment: exactly! : and the main difference is that .AAR files include resources :D

Comment: Thanks it works! I think it's also important to say that in this way, you have to do: File -> New module -> Import aar/jar, and then add the dependencie  in the module settings, and linking it. Thanks Again!

Answer (score 0):

Look into AAR files.  They are Android libraries that can contain not only code, but also resources!

Answer (score 0):

**AAR:** Look up AAR files etc. The way I do it is:

```
uploadArchives {
 repositories.mavenDeployer {
    repository(url: "someDirectory/")
}
```

}

Then `./gradlew clean build uploadArchives`

---

**JAR:** If you don't have a resource file, just add this to your build.gradle:

```
task makeJarRelease(type: Copy) {
    from("build/intermediates/bundles/release/")
    into("some_directory/")
    include("classes.jar")
    rename("classes.jar", "yourlibname.jar")
}
```

Then run a `./gradlew clean build makeJarRelease`

And that will do it.

Yeah, Android Studio exports .AAR files and that is the new standard. However, if you need a jarfile, thats how you can do it.

Again, you *cannot* have a res folder (meaning no XML files or drawables) if you want to do it this way.

Comment: yeah but in this way I just have the classes...and I can use it as an external library..cause I need also other resources

Comment: Then you have to do what everyone else is saying and export as an AAR file.